# Python - Error importing wx

Tags: python, unix, wxwidgets

I'm trying to import matplotlib in Scientific Linux release 6.4 and keep getting the following error (whether using a script or iPython):

> matplotlib backend_wx and backend_wxagg require wxpython >=2.8

I've tried importing wx first (with or without importing wxversion first and setting the version to 3.0) but then get the error:

> ----> 1 import wx
>
> /cm/shared/languages/Python-2.7.6/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2/wx/**init**.py
>   in ()
>        43
>        44 # Load the package namespace with the core classes and such
>   ---> 45 from wx._core import *
>        46 del wx
>        47
>
> /cm/shared/languages/Python-2.7.6/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2/wx/_core.py
>   in ()
>         2 # Don't modify this file, modify the SWIG interface instead.
>         3
>   ----> 4 import *core*
>         5 import new
>         6 new_instancemethod = new.instancemethod
>
> ImportError: libwx_gtk2u_xrc-3.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file:
>   No such file or directory

I've gone through several threads offering possible solutions but haven't found any that work for me as I don't have admin rights on this computer. Does anyone have a solution to this that doesn't involve moving or modifying the package files?

Thanks

(Edit - I'm waiting to hear back from the sysadmin but would like to know if there's anything I can do in the meantime.)

Comment: what's yoour OS/toolkit and their versions? How was wxpython installed? From sources or from repository?

Comment: I'm using Scientific Linux release 6.4. I don't have any information about how programs were installed and also can't reinstall anything.

Comment: please update with this information. It looks either the wxpython installation was not done correctly or the version installed is incompatible with GTK+ or its dependencies. Out of curiosity - can you download and build wxWidgets-3.0.3 (latest). You don't have to install it, just do `../configure && make`. If that fails, check the log file/error message on what is missing. It is also possible that not everything was copied on you dev machine from the build environment.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this and it completed with no errors.

Comment: are you able to find `libwx_gtk2u_xrc-3.0.so.0` in there?